# How to set batch size and epoch value in Keras for infinite data set?

Tags: keras

I want to feed images to a Keras CNN. The program randomly feeds either an image downloaded from the net, or an image of random pixel values. How do I set batch size and epoch number? My training data is essentially infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your dataset is infinite, you have to set both batch size and number of epochs.

For batch size, you can use the largest batch size that fits into your GPU/CPU RAM, by just trial and error. For example you can try power of two batch sizes like 32, 64, 128, 256.

For number of epochs, this is a parameter that always has to be tuned for the specific problem. You can use a validation set to then train until the validation loss is maximized, or the training loss is almost constant (it converges). Make sure to use a different part of the dataset to decide when to stop training. Then you can report final metrics on another different set (the test set).

Comment: Maybe my question should have been, why does batch and epoch size need to be more than 1. For my needs I can programmatically flip a coin and either load an image from the net or generate a field of random pixels on the fly. I don't understand the need to collect, say, 64 images into memory and then feed them through. I'm still feeding them through one at a time.

Comment: @user3825715 It stabilizes training as the gradient is quite noisy with a single example per batch.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I think the OP's comment question is still valid though regarding epochs. If you have infinite data, why would setting number of epochs do anything since the data never cycles. Isn't epochs=1 fine if you have infinite data?

Answer (score 0):

It is because implementations are vectorised for faster & efficient execution. When the data is large, all the data cannot fit the memory & hence we use batch size to still get some vectorisation. 
In my opinion, one should use a batch size as large as your machine can handle.